# Plot percentage values with or without % symbol

Tags: notation, percentages, article-writing

I found on some plots percentage values followed by % symbol (e.g. x%=2%) and on some plots percentage values have not symbol % (e.g. x%=2).
What is the best solution for a scientific article?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the % in -- if anything, it removes ambiguity and makes it clear exactly what you are trying to say over.